# Amplified Sound in another room

Tags: acoustics

I was sitting in my room with my door open, because I have a cooler in my room that has a lot of noise when turned on. I was watching a video on my phone, but because of the noise from the cooler, I couldnt hear it and I had to increase the volume. However, my brother comes from the adjacent room and tells me he can hear the sounds from my phone very clearly and loudly, although his door was closed. I cant seem to understand this phenomenon. How can he hear sounds from my phone clearly, when I myself cant hear it clearly due to the cooler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several reasons are at work here, as follows.

First, if the cooler fan is closest to you, then you will be bothered by it more than your brother, who is farther away.

Second, the noise made by a cooler fan is well-blocked by walls and doors, whereas music and speech is less-well blocked.

Third, random noise (as from a cooler fan) is fundamentally less bothersome than speech and music, to which your hearing "software" is far more sensitive.

A practical application of these effects is called *masking*, where the sound system speakers in a busy, open office are fed a random whoosh noise which renders speech in an adjacent cubicle inaudible to you. In fact, after several days in such an office, you get used to the whoosh noise coming from the speakers and you stop hearing it altogether. The office seems to your ears to be perfectly quiet, even though it is not!